Rough edges on pgfplots contour
I am trying to make some filled contour plots using tikz and pgfplots. I am following the examples on the manual https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-3dplots#sec-4.6.9. The manual shows the contour plots with smooth edges, but when I compile it in my computer the result looks quite bad, with rough edges. The result is the same wether I compile it on Overleaf or using VsCode.
This is one of the examples I am trying to reproduce
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={$x \exp(-x^2-y^2)$},
    domain=-2:2,
    view={0}{90},
    colorbar horizontal,
]
    \addplot3 [
        contour filled={
            number=14,
        },
    ] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This is the result

Whereas the example on the manual looks like this

I tried increasing the number of samples but I cannot go over 100, I tried using contour gnuplot which gives smoother edges but I couldn't find how to get it filled.
I am actually trying to make a sketch of a double well potential like this

I made this in Julia using Cairo Makie, but it is not quite what I am looking for, I would like a smoother transition and I am planning to overlay some sketch using tikz on top of the contour plot so it would be nice to produce the contour plot in tiks as well.

Which pdf viewer do you use? It looks fine in the internal viewer of texstudio, but fuzzy e.g. in mac Preview.app and overleaf

I used the preview on Overleaf, in the mac preview app and vscode the image also looks fuzzy.

Ok so I downloaded adobe pdf reader and indeed the edges of the contour plot are smooth. I didn't know this was a viewer issue. Thanks.

This is the output of your code viewed in Acrobat Reader on mac:

Not bad, but not perfect. - mac Preview does a really bad job.
This is the warning from the manual section 4.6.9 about "Filled Contour Plots":

Beware: Viewer Limitations The following paragraph makes uses of pdf
features which are un- supported by some free viewers (including
pdf.js and evince). Please resort to a suitable viewer if you see
unexpected results.

Many viewers(most viewers? all viewers?) has problems showing the filled contours. You are clearly using different viewers for the manual and your output.

Thanks I now opened it with adobe and the edges look smooth. I didn't know this is a viewer issue.
